# Concatenating regex variables in fieldvalue

Tags: biblatex

Friends, I'm stuck with a doubt about how to concatenate values from `regex` parenthesis into the `fieldvalue` mapping option. Let's see a quick working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{fruits,
  title = {The apple and the banana},
  publisher = {Tomatopress},
  editor = {Straw Berry},
  author = {Annoying Orange},
  year = {1970}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map[overwrite]{
            \step[fieldsource=title,
                  fieldset=title,
                  match=\regexp{(\w+)\s+(\w+).*},
                  fieldvalue={$1}
            ]
            \step[fieldset=title,
                  fieldvalue={~$2},
                  append
            ]
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

Hello world \cite{fruits}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The idea here is quite simple: get the first two words of the `title` key, in my case, `$1 = The` and `$2 = apple`. The output is as expected:

[image: Output]

Note that in my code I used two `\step`'s: one setting `fieldvalue` to `$1` and the other appending `$2` (preceded by a non-breaking space) to it. I was hoping to save a step and try the following code (preferably I'd prefer a breakable space):

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map[overwrite]{
            \step[fieldsource=title,
                  fieldset=title,
                  match=\regexp{(\w+)\s+(\w+).*},
                  fieldvalue={$1~$2}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. I know I could use the `replace` mapping option - actually, this MWE is too simple - and the expansion of those two variables work, but for the project we are working on, we have to use `fieldvalue`. I was wondering how can I add an arbitrary number of variables in a `fieldvalue` all at once instead of incrementally using `\step`'s to append the values.

Any ideas? `:)`

Comment: Can you expand why you cannot use the `replace` mapping option?

Comment: @Guido: Sure! `:)` In my real file, I have different keys for `fieldsource` and `fieldset`, where regex is applied to the value of the first key and then the result is stored in the value of the second key. If I use `replace`, both keys have their values changed, and not only the one pointed by `fieldset`. I'm not sure if I'm using this feature correctly, but `fieldvalue` gave me the correct attribution. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda If this is for a custom style, consider upgrading to 2.4, where Philip has introduced `\DeclareStyleSourcemap`. This way you don't have to worry about the user-level `\DeclareSourcemap` overriding all of your mapping rules.

Comment: @Audrey: Thanks a million for the hint, Audrey! I'll take a look at `\DeclareStyleSourcemap`. `:)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a bug in biber 1.3. Please try version 1.4 from Sourceforge. You'll also need to be using the biblatex 2.4 beta from SourceForge. You might also want to wrap the `$1~$2` in `\regexp{}` to stop biblatex turning the `~` into `\nobreakspace {}` if it matters to you (the `fieldvalue` is sanitised specially because it ends up as an XML attribute in the biber .bcf file).